# Parse all strings of specific length?

Tags: text-processing, files, wildcards, pattern-matching

I've exported my email archive of 10 years which is very large.

I want to parse all the text for any string that is 64 characters long in search of a bitcoin private key.

How can I parse strings of a certain length in characters?

Comment: What format are the emails in? Plain text? Maildir?

Comment: @Sparhawk I'm still downloading the files, I'm hoping they are in `txt` or something I can `cat` and parse with a pipe.

Comment: @Sparhawk file type is mbox, hoping to convert it into `txt` for easy parsing

Comment: What do you mean by "parse" here? Do you just want to find all strings of exactly 64 characters and _then_ parse them? And how are strings defined? Can we assume you mean things that are delineated with whitespace? So anything with a space, a tab, a newline etc on either side of it? And what operating system are you using? Is it Linux? Can we assume you have access to GNU tools?

Comment: The entire email file is a "string of certain length"; IMHO, the string you're looking for consists of certain characters and is delimited in some way. What can you say about the string besides it being 64 of some character?

Comment: @JeffSchaller a bitcoin private key but I was hoping for a method I could modify to use for ethereum and other alt-coin private keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have GNU `grep` (default on Linux), you can do:

```
grep -Po '(^|\s)\S{64}(\s|$)' file
```

The `-P` enables Perl Compatible Regular Expressions, which give us `\b` (word-boundaries) `\S` (non-whitespace) and `{N}` (find exactly N characters), and the `-o` means "print only the matching part of the line. Then, we look for stretches of non-whitespace that are exactly 64 characters long that are either at the beginning of the line (`^`) or after whitespace (`'s`) and which end either at the end of the line (`$`) or with another whitespace character.

Note that the result will include any whitespace characters at the beginning and end of the string, so if you want to parse this further, you might want to use this instead:

```
grep -Po '(^|\s)\K\S{64}(?=\s|$)'
```

That will look for a whitespace character or the beginning of the string `(\s|^)`, then discard it `\K` and then look for 64 non-whitespace characters followed by (the `(?=foo)` is called a "[lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)" and will not be included in the match) either a whitespace character, or the end of the line.

Comment: pcre also gives us *negative* lookahead and lookbehind assertions: `grep -Po '(?<!\S)\S{64}(?!\S)'` is enough to find runs of 64 non-spaces; but please read my [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/492734/313992) for why that's probably not what's intended.

Comment: @pizdelect yes, I know negative lookbehinds, but I find the `\K` approach much more readable and elegant.

Comment: elegance is not my strong point, but your 1st example will also include the delimiting spaces in the output, and the 2nd example will *not* match words which start at the beginning of the line.

Comment: @pizdelect well yes, that's why I included the second example with the lookarounds. But you're right about the second, that's a typo (see the description which I ncludes the start), thanks for pointing it out. Fixed now.

Answer (score 8):

If you mean to search for a 256-bit number in hexadecimal form (64 chars from the range `0-9` and `A-F` -- one of the formats in which a bitcoin private key could appear), this should do:

```
egrep -aro '\<[A-F0-9]{64}\>' files and dirs ...
```

Add the `-i` option or also include the `a-f` range if some of the keys are in lowercase.

For the general problem of finding runs of characters from the same class having a specified length, you would better use pcre regexps, which could be used with GNU grep with the `-P` option. For instance, to find runs of uppercase letters from any charset, of min length of 2 and max length of 4, and which are delimited by chars which are not uppercase letters:

```
echo ÁRVÍZtűrő tükörFÚRÓgép |
   LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 grep -Po '(?<!\p{Lu})\p{Lu}{2,4}(?!\p{Lu})'
FÚRÓ
```

Replace `\p{Lu}` with `\p{Ll}` for lowercase letters, `\S` for non-spaces, etc. See [here](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcresyntax.html#SEC3) and [here](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcresyntax.html#SEC4) for the full list.

`(?<!...)` and `(?!...)` are *negative* lookbehind and lookahead *zero-width* assertions; e.g. `(?<!<)\w(?!>)` will match a "word" character when not bracketed by `<` and `>`. The `\<` zero-width assertion from `vi` could be implemented by `(?<!\w)(?=\w)`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to find all words of length 64 from `/path/to/file`, you can use

```
tr -c '[:alnum:]' '\n' < /path/to/file | grep '^.\{64\}$'
```

This replaces all non-alphanumeric characters by newlines, so each word is on its own line. Then it filters this result to include only the words of length 64.

Comment: What about dot (`.`), comma (`,`), colon (`:`), semicolon (`;`) and many other usual punctuation characters, shoudln't those also be converted to a newline ?

Comment: @Isaac why? Why are you assuming they can't appear inside the target string?

Comment: @terdon Because I assume that the target string is a **bitcoin private key** which is usually a [64 hex character string](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Private_key). Hmmm, ooops, sorry, the OP stated that: I am not assuming then.

Comment: @Isaac You're not wrong

Answer (score 3):

It seems that grep is the correct tool to "search" for an string. What is left to do is to define such string with a regex. The first issue is to define the limits of a word. It is not as simple as "an space", as `a book, a lamp` use `,` as word delimiter, in the same concept, many other characters, or even the start or end of a line could act as word delimiter. There are some word delimiters in GNU grep:

- `\<` word start.
- `\>` word end.
- `\b` word boundary.

All of them assume that a word is a sequence of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` characters. If that is ok for you, this regex could work:

```
 grep -o '\<.\{64\}\>' file
```

If you could use extended regex, the `\` could be reduced:

```
 grep -oE '\<.{64}\>' file
```

That selects from a "word start" (`\<`), 64 (`{64}`) characters (`.`), to a "word end" (`\>`) and prints only the matching (`-o`) parts.

However, the dot (`.`) will match **any** character, that may be too much.

If you want to be more strict on the selection (hex digits), use:

```
 grep -oE '\<[0-9a-fA-F]{64}\>' file
```

Which will allow hex digits in lowercase **or** uppercase. But if you really want to be strict, as some non-ASCII characters might be included, use:

```
 LC_ALL=C grep -oE '\<[0-9a-fA-F]{64}\>' file
```

Some implementations of grep (as grep -P) do not have a "start of word" or "end of word" (as `\<` and `\>`) but have "word boundary" (as `\b`):

```
grep -oP '\b[0-9a-fA-F]{64}\b' file
```

There are some languages that [accept the POSIX word boundaries `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`, but not perl, and only from PCRE 8.34](http://www.regexguru.com/2014/05/new-regular-expression-features-in-pcre-8-34-and-8-35/).

And [there are a lot more flavors of "word boundaries"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refwordboundaries.html).